# PHP Mysql Fetching

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP isn't working. I get nothing as a result:

I am trying to get information from a MySQL database. The database contains one table that has four entries in it with the following two rows: PinNumber and SwitchStatus

here are the values in the database
PinNumber = 3
SwitchStatus = 0

PinNumber = 5
SwitchStatus = 0

PinNumber = 6
SwitchStatus = 0

PinNumber = 9
SwitchStatus = 0

This is the code that I am trying to use without success:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("QuickFox");

$fetch = ("SELECT * FROM Switches"));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
{
echo "$row['*']";   
}
```

Comment: 1. mysql_* functions are deprecated, 2. use fetch_array only when its needed, otherwise use fetch_assoc 3. missing query, 4. use SELECT * only when its needed, otherwise SELECT item1, item2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break your code down and analyze it.

First off, your problem is that you are not calling `mysql_query` to get a MySQL object which you will use in the `mysql_fetch_array` function. So you need to implement:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Switches");
```

This should clear up your errors and give you results. Now for other things. You have too many closing parenthesis in

```
$fetch = ("SELECT * FROM Switches"));
                                   ^
```

but you do not need them to begin with. `$fetch = "SELECT * FROM Switches";` is acceptable. Also, you do NOT need to use quotes when getting the results

```
echo "$row['*']";
     ^         ^
```

The use of `echo $row[];` is acceptable or you may have to use

```
echo "{$row[]}";
      ^      ^
```

However, this line is entirely WRONG. There will not be any column `*` in the returned array. Yes you said `SELECT *` but the database does not really return `*`. You need to use the name of the columns return as such:

```
echo $row['PinNumber'];
```

**NOTICE**: Do not use MySQL_* functions for they have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* functions or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) before `mysql_fetch_array`.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
{
    var_dump( $row );
}
```

Be aware that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and in new code I'd suggest using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) instead ([which?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php))

Answer (score 0):

```
$fetch = ("SELECT * FROM Switches"));   
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
    {
    echo "$row[*]"; 
    }
```

Try changing to this:

```
 $fetch = "SELECT * FROM Switches";
 $fetch = mysql_query($fetch);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
{
  echo $row['PinNumber']." = ".$row['SwitchStatus'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
  mysql_select_db("QuickFox");

  $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT PinNumber,SwitchStatus FROM Switches");

  while(list($PinNumber,$SwitchStatus) = mysql_fetch_row($fetch)){
    echo "PinNumber = $PinNumber SwitchStatus = $SwitchStatus";   
  }
```